# What does the star besides some unknown achievements mean?

Tags: kittens-game

I only have the *Unicorn Conspiracy* achievement, all other achievements are displayed as:

> ???

Some of them have a yellow star on the right side (numbers 12, 23, 24).

What does this yellow star mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The following Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/comments/3ryg2t/gold_star_in_achievements/) post clarifies the difference between "normal" and gold star achievements.

> gold is for getting it in a single run

More info given in a later post (small text is Question, big text answer by bloodrizer:

> ```
> Does that apply for just that one, or for any ungotten achievement?
> ```
>
> So far only for 40K.
>
> ```
> And does it mean that I will be awarded a gold star when I get it?
> ```
>
> Yep, I mostly did it for your run.
>
> ```
> Is it an actual award, or basically just an asterisk letting you know about it?
> ```
>
> I don't know how to reply to this.
>
> ```
> Are there other kinds of stars?
> ```
>
> Only regular and "gold" variations for achievements.
>
> ```
> And what does a "single run" mean within the context of that achievement
> ```
>
> Having reached 40K year on current playthrough.

Comment: -1 as this is actually incorrect. The star represents that the achivement has an Insane version which you can see in the Wiki. **Spoilers Warning** http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Achievements